# Magento 2 : How to Override Checkout Process

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, event-observer, exception

I have created an observer event in custom extension. I want to check something before order will be created. When condition not true then checkout process schould be break and go back to cart. Here is my code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_before">
       <observer name="company_module_observer_check" instance="Company\Module\Observer\Check" />
   </event> 
</config>
```

and

```
class Check implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /** @var  LoggerInterface */
    protected $logger;
    /**
     *
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

       //TOTO i want do things like below
        $condition // condition will be got from an API service 
        if($condition){
             return $this;
        }else{
            return // Go back to cart
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: try to throw a exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can used code like this :

```
class Check implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory, \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url; 
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    enter code here
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

       //TOTO i want do things like below
        $condition // condition will be got from an API service 
        if($condition){
             return $this;
        }else{
            // Go back to cart
            $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();            
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```